# ROS2 colcon bulid Error

Tags: ros2, colcon

[image]

If a package in a merged underlay workspace is overridden and it installs headers, then all packages in the overlay must sort their include directories by workspace order. Failure to do so may result in build failures or undefined behavior at run time.
If the overridden package is used by another package in any underlay, then the overriding package in the overlay must be API and ABI compatible or undefined behavior at run time may occur.
﻿
If you understand the risks and want to override a package anyways, add the following to the command line:
--allow-overriding turn_on_wheeltec_robot

Comment: Please paste any code or console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)...

Answer (score 0):

This message is basically telling the following information:

1. You've already built this package, running `colcon build` again will rebuild this package in current workspace (i.e. ~/wheeltec_ros2)
2. The existed package is located in /home/wheeltec/wheeltec_ros2/install/turn_on_wheeltec_robot
3. If paths got messed up, for example, you source different setup.bash, some other packages that depend on this package may not work properly
4. If you just want to override the existed package by this newly built package, apply `--allow-overriding` to your command

The above is the explanation of what this output tells... I am not sure what are you trying to ask though...

If you are sure to override the existed package (based on the fact that you put them in the same path, I assume that's what you want?), then you can run the following command instead to get rid of this warning message:

```
$ colcon build --packages-select --allow-overriding turn_on_wheeltec_robot
```

You may also want to take a look at discussion on [this thread](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/issues/465), where people discuss what are the best practice they would do when build packages.